# Reverse a linked list as big as having 7 million nodes efficiently using Threads

Tags: multithreading, singly-linked-list, divide-and-conquer

I was asked this question to reverse a singly linked list as big as having 7 million nodes by using threads efficiently. Using recursion doesn't look feasible if there are so many nodes so I opted for divide and conquer where in each thread be given a chunk of linked list which gets reversed by just making the node pointer point back to previous node by store a reference to current, future and past node and later adding it with  reversed chunks from other threads. But the interviewer insisted that the size of the link list is not know, and you can do it without finding the size in an efficient manner. Well I couldn't figure it out , how would you go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such questions I like to implement "top-down":

1. Assume that you already have a Class that implement Runnable or extends Thread out of which you can create instances and run, each instance receives two parameters: a pointer to a Node in the List and number of Nodes to reverse
2. Your `main` traverse all 7 million nodes and "marks" the starting points for your threads, say we have 7 threads, the marked points will be: 1, 1,000,000, 2,000,000,... save the marked nodes in an array or whichever data-structure you like
3. After you finished "marking the starting points, create the threads and give each one of them its starting point and the counter 1,000,000
4. After all the threads are done, "glue" each of the marking points to point back to the last node of the previous thread (which should be saved in another "static" ordered data-structure).

Now that we have a plan - all that's left to do is implement a (considerably easy) algorithm that, give the number N and a Node x, it will reverse the next N nodes (including x) in a singly linked list :)